# Listen to custom event from js code in script tags vue2

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, vuejs2, custom-events

I emit custom event from one of great-grandson of my `app.vue` main component like this:

```
this.$emit('logged');
```

And now I want to listen to this event in my `app.vue` main component but I would rather do it from javascript within `<script>` tags than from `<template>`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-header></app-header>
        <router-view></router-view>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import header from './components/shared/header.vue';
    import footer from './components/shared/footer.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            'app-header': header,
            'app-footer': footer
        }
    }

// can I listen to custom events somewhere here above?
</script>
```

Is this possible to listen to custom event from js code in vue 2? I couldn't find such information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) and [Non Parent-Child Communication](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) in the docs.

Events emitted from a component do not bubble up more than one level, so you won't be able to directly listen for the `logged` event emitted by a great grandchild component from your main component unless you proxy the event upwards at each level.

Alternatively you could use an event bus for non parent-child communication (see above link).

This is how you would listen for an event in code:

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <my-component ref="mycomp"></my-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  mounted() {
    // You need to have a reference to the component you want to listen to
    // which is why I'm using refs here
    this.$refs.mycomp.$on('logged', () => {
      alert('Got logged event');
    });
  }
}

</script>
```

But really in the above situation you'd just use `v-on`. If you are using an event bus, then you need to use [`$on()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) and [`$off()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off) programmatically. I won't explain the event bus pattern because I'm sure it's been widely discussed on SO already.

Comment: Is using vuex centralized state also good approach? Basically I want to re-render some of content using boolean variable which should be accessible across entire app to use it within `v-if` directive in multiple different components.

Comment: Vuex is used to share state across components, yes you could do that.